# Preventing insert duplicate values in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have simply made an online exam program in php and mysql. I have taken a mock test for this and found that the answer is submitting successfully except 5/6 students answer inserting double, that is duplicate entries found. That means out of 30 / 40 questions students answers are saving 34 / 45 etc. question answers. Please help me I am not a master in mysql. Here is my code given.

```
$exam->data = array(
        ':usr_id'               =>  $stud_id,
        ':exam_id'              =>  $exam_id,
        ':qust_id'              =>  $question_id
    );
    
    $exam->query = "SELECT * FROM `user_exams_answer` WHERE `user_id` = :usr_id AND `exam_id` = :exam_id AND `question_id` = :qust_id";
    $total_rowqq = $exam->total_row();
    
    if($total_rowqq == 0){
        $exam->data = array(
                ':user_answer_option'   =>  $answer_option,
                ':marks'                =>  $marks,
                ':usr_id'               =>  $stud_id,
                ':exam_id'              =>  $exam_id,
                ':qust_id'              =>  $question_id
        );      
        $exam->query = "INSERT INTO `user_exams_answer`(`user_id`, `exam_id`, `question_id`, `user_answer_option`, `marks`) VALUES(:usr_id, :exam_id, :qust_id, :user_answer_option, :marks)";
        $exam->execute_query();     

        $output = "Option has been saved.";
        
    }else{
    $exam->data = array(
        ':user_answer_option'   =>  $answer_option,
        ':marks'                =>  $marks,
        ':usr_id'               =>  $stud_id,
        ':exam_id'              =>  $exam_id,
        ':qust_id'              =>  $question_id
    );      
        $exam->query = "UPDATE `user_exams_answer` SET `user_answer_option` = :user_answer_option, `marks` = :marks WHERE `user_id` = :usr_id AND `exam_id` = :exam_id AND `question_id` = :qust_id";
        $exam->execute_query();     

        $output = "Option has been modified.";
    }
    
    echo $output;
```

Here sometime it is inserting double/ triple values in mysql table. Is it the problem of multiple sessions ?
Please help how to overcome from this duplicate values

Comment: make a combined UNIQUE user_id,exam_id,qust_id, so that thexy can't be entered doulbe

Comment: What nbk said. Instead of running the select query to check if a row already exists (this is vulnerable to race condition on parallel request insert after check but before insert), add a unique index to your table. So, you want the uniqueness constraint to be maintained in the database itself rather than in your application layer. If you are using MySQL, the query would be:

ALTER TABLE user_exams_answer 
ADD CONSTRAINT uidx_user_exam_question UNIQUE KEY (user_id, exam_id, question_id);

Comment: That means if I use combined UNIQUE KEY for user_id, exam_id, question_id fields, than no need to select query to check if a row already exists?  Here One student can add several answers for different questions, exams?

Comment: Which is the easiest way to insert record if not exists, Please help, I am just learning.

Comment: See INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: I have so many data in the table, now how can i ALTER TABLE for UNIQUE KEY

Comment: Did you read the manual? :)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html
https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/sql_unique.asp